# Nifi: Write Custom processor for updating data in hdfs files

Tags: apache-nifi

I want  to make  custom processor  form   which  i can  get  file  from hdfs and  then update it's  content's  value and  here  is  several things  i am  interested in:

1. Is  is   convenient to use workflow   like  this  listHdfs+fetchHdfs+my  custom processor (in which  i would   have  logic  like  fetchFile processor and  some  extra  details   which is appropriate for  my task ?
2. **Should  i  implement  fetch HDFS   logic  instead  of  fetch File?**
3. Can i use  ListHdfs  and  fetchFile  together?

Comment: Is there some custom logic you have to perform while the file(s) are being fetched? Otherwise it seems like you should just use ListHDFS -> FetchHDFS -> your custom processor to operate on the contents and metadata.

Comment: i want to  fetch only  unique  files  i mean  i  down't  want to   fetch  the  same    files  every  time   i start  processor  ,  in this case  i  want to  fetch  only  newly added  ones or  flowfiles  which were updated

Comment: That's how List/Fetch works now, unless you clear the processor state